# Необходимо сверстать секцию, как показано ниже. Как сделать так, чтобы рамка заходила на изображение? Абсолютное позиционирование нельзя применять

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image: Макет в фотошопе]

```css
.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
}

.products-section {
  margin: 0px 13.8%;
}
.product-item {
  width: 29%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product-item:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: 66px
}

.product-banner {
  width: 100%;
}

.product-content {
  border: 3px solid #e1d8bd; 
  padding: 70px 30px;
}

.product-link {
  color: #b59f5b
}

.product-button {
  width: 140px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #b59f5b; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-section">
      <h2 class="products-tittle">Наши изделия</h2>
      <div class="products">
        <div class="product-item">
          <picture class="product-banner">
            <source srcset="images/shop-item-mobile1.jpg 1x" media="(max-width: 640px)">
            <source srcset="images/shop-item-tablet1.jpg 1x" media="(min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1200px)">
            <source srcset="images/shop-item-desk1.jpg 1x" media="(min-width: 1201px)">
            <img src="images/shop-item-desk1.jpg 1x" class="product-banner-image" alt="Фото подушки">
          </picture>
          <div class="product-content">
            <h3 class="product-tittle">Подушки на диван</h3>
            <p>Набор из двух подушек с модными принтами. Видео о создании <a href="#0" class="product-link">здесь</a>.</p>
            <span class="cost-strikeout">1000₽</span>
            <span class="cost">800₽</span>
            <button type="button" class="product-button">В магазин</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-item">            
          <picture class="product-banner">
            <source srcset="images/shop-item-mobile2.jpg 1x" media="(max-width: 640px)">
            <source srcset="images/shop-item-tablet2.jpg 1x" media="(min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1200px)">
            <source srcset="images/shop-item-desk2.jpg 1x" media="(min-width: 1201px)">
            <img src="images/shop-item-desk2.jpg 1x" class="product-image" alt="Фото куклы Зайчик">
          </picture>
          <div class="product-content">
            <h3 class="product-tittle">Кукла "Зайчик"</h3>
            <p>Интреьерная рукодельная кукла "Зайчик", созданию которой посвящена <a href="#0" class="product-link">весенняя серия постов</a> в блоге и несколько подкастов.</p>
            <span class="cost">3500₽</span>
            <button type="button" class="product-button">В магазин</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-item">
          <picture class="product-banner">
            <source srcset="images/shop-item-mobile3.jpg 1x" media="(max-width: 640px)">
            <source srcset="images/shop-item-tablet3.jpg 1x" media="(min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1200px)">
            <source srcset="images/shop-item-desk3.jpg 1x" media="(min-width: 1201px)">
            <img src="images/shop-item-desk3.jpg 1x" class="product-image" alt="Фото рамки">
          </picture>
          <div class="product-content">
            <h3 class="product-tittle">Шестиугольная рамка</h3>
            <p>Необычная рамка для украшения дома из видео <a href="#0" class="product-link">"Как сделать рамку из подручных средств за 30 минут"</a></p>
            <span class="cost-strikeout">500₽</span>
            <span class="cost">400₽</span>
            <button type="button" class="product-button">В магазин</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

всё получилось через отрицательный margin

Comment: Ответ непонятен. Просьба расширить необходимой дополнительной информацией.